# Unloading huge data from Cassandra table

Tags: spring-batch, spring-data-cassandra

We have a table with 15 million records and one of the columns stores huge XML. Requirement is generate 30 different text files with different fields of XML with all the data (15+ million) from table. 
And all   these 30 jobs will run at the same time.
Often we are getting into ReadTimeoutException. Due to time constraints, we can’t think of caching solutions.
How can we mitigate these readtimeout exception? Any help will be greatful.
Below are the spring batch and Cassandra version used
Cassandra – 3.11, using Spring Batch – 3.x as unloads framework.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the read_request_timeout_in_ms value in your cassandra configuration?

Comment: How do you perform fetching? just `select * from table`?